# Other states than "change" for radio buttons in polymer

Tags: javascript, events, radio-button, polymer-1.0

I'd like to have a group of radio button which select either if a map of france or a map of the world should be displayed. My problem is that polymer official documentation only states "change" as event for radio button state. So the problem is that with my current code below, clicking on the different radio buttons will work just as intended, but clicking on a radio button which is already selected will fire this "change" event (which is a wrong behavior in my opinion, since the button state is still "selected", nothing as changed. So my question is the following: is there any other event for radio buttons state? I tried "checked", "selected", but none of these seems to work...

here's my code:

```
<div id="mapSelector">
<paper-radio-group id="mapSelectors" selected="radioWorld">
    <paper-radio-button id="radioFrance" name="radioFrance">France map</paper-radio-button>
    <paper-radio-button id="radioWorld" name="radioWorld">World map</paper-radio-button>
</paper-radio-group>
</div>

<div id="containerFrance" hidden="{{hideFrance}}" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;">
</div>

<div id="containerWorld" hidden="{{hideWorld}}" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;">
</div>



</template>

<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'page-maps',
    listeners: {
        'radioFrance.change': 'toggleMaps',
        'radioWorld.change': 'toggleMaps'
    },
    hideFrance: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false
    },
    hideWorld: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: true
    },
    toggleMaps: function () {
        this.hideFrance = this.hideWorld;
        this.hideWorld = !this.hideWorld;
    }
});
</script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the change event but then check the value of your toggle button in the callback, like so:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'page-maps',
  listeners: {
      'radioFrance.change': 'toggleMaps',
      'radioWorld.change': 'toggleMaps'
  },
  hideFrance: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: false
  },
  hideWorld: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: true
  },
  toggleMaps: function (e) {
      if(e.srcElement.value == false){
          //do some code
      }else{
          //do some other code
      }
  }
});
```